# Function graph tracer for android

Tags: android, debugging, linux-kernel, arm, trace

I am trying to use graph tracer to measure time latency. I am able to configure function tracer but not able to configure function graph tracer. When i try to use the kernel image with function graph tracer enabled at the boot time it says `not syncing vfs unable to mount root fs on unknown-block 0 0`

Kernel version - 3.0.21

Is function graph tracer is supported to for arm architecture?

Thanks

Comment: Are you building a new kernel image for this? or how do you set it in boot params? It looks like you are messing up something else.

Comment: i am building a new kernel image. But only when i enable trace_functions_graph configuration this error is coming. With CONFIG_FUNCTION_TRACER it is working fine and able to take the trace.

Comment: It must be something else. You get a vfs error for root fs configuration. or of course may be a strange bug.